# NRPE: Unable to read output with check_connections plugin

Tags: nrpe

I'm using plugin which gives me warning or crtis  with established connections.
If I run it on local machine it gives:

```
*root@graber:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ./check_connections -w 1 -c 5 -C sshd
CRITICAL  Established connections: 6*
```

I know, I run as root. But:

**Rights to the file:**

```
root@graber:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ls -all check_connections
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios 5459 2012-07-06 10:19 check_connections
```

**/etc/sudoers:**

```
root@graber:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# cat /etc/sudoers
Defaults        env_reset
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/lsof
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
```

**/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg:**

```
*nrpe_user=nagios
nrpe_group=nagios*
*dont_blame_nrpe=1*
*command_prefix=/usr/bin/sudo
command[check_connections]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_connections -w 1 -c 5 -C sshd*
```

**log from remote:**

```
*2012-07-06T11:12:49+02:00 graber nrpe[25928]: Handling the connection...
2012-07-06T11:12:49+02:00 graber nrpe[25928]: Host address is in allowed_hosts
2012-07-06T11:12:49+02:00 graber nrpe[25928]: Host is asking for command 'check_connections' to be run...
2012-07-06T11:12:49+02:00 graber nrpe[25928]: Running command: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_connections -w 1 -c 5 -C sshd
2012-07-06T11:19:11+02:00 graber nrpe[26100]: Return Code: 2, Output: NRPE: Unable to read output*
```

Why is this happening? I'm out of ideas, I've searched google for 2 days now :)

Comment: I'm not sure right now, but shouldn't that line in /etc/sudoers be `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/*` ?

Comment: well I tried with *, also tried adding path to the file (/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_connections). No effect whatsoever

Comment: Seems like a permissions problem. How does check_connections work? Does it read or write to some file or device as root?

Comment: nope. it reads number of established connections and displays the outcome as (as example of course) "WARNING Established connections 3" as seen above. No write on disk take place

Comment: it works! The problem was with absence of utils.pm in certain locations. All I had to do is to run script with sudo -u nagios and check output. thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

it works! The problem was with absence of utils.pm in certain locations. All I had to do is to run script with sudo -u nagios and check output. thanks for help!